# how to expand date by week and by month in shell?

Tags: bash, shell, date, sh

In short, I want something works like this:

1. When I input a date like `2012-12-27` and want to expand the date by
   week(start with Monday), it
   outputs:`2012-12-24,2012-12-25,2012-12-26,2012-12-27,2012-12-28,2012-12-29,2012-12-30`
2. When I input a date like `2012-12-27` and want to expand the date by month, it outputs:`2012-12-01,2012-12-02 ... 2012-12-31`

or, how can I group a bunch of dates by week? e.g. when I input`2012-12-01,2012-12-02 ... 2012-12-31`. It outputs:`2012-12-01,2012-12-02|2012-12-03 ... 2012-12-09|2012-12-10 ... 2012-12-16|...|2012-12-31`

I have no idea how to complete this, any clue may be helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DAYSECS=86400                          # seconds in a day
WEEKSECS=604800

echo "Expand on week:"

g_epoch=$(date +"%s" -d $1)            # given date as seconds from epoch
g_dayno=$(date +"%u" -d $1)            # given date as day of week
g_month=$(date +"%m" -d $1)            # given month
g_year=$(date +"%Y" -d $1)             # given year

s_epoch=$(($g_epoch - $DAYSECS * ($g_dayno - 1)))
e_epoch=$(($s_epoch + $WEEKSECS))
for etime in $(seq $s_epoch $DAYSECS $e_epoch); do
  date +"%Y-%m-%d" -d "@$etime"
done

echo "Expand on month:"

s_epoch=$(date +"%s" -d "$g_year-$g_month-01")
e_epoch=$(($s_epoch + 4 * $WEEKSECS))
for etime in $(seq $s_epoch $DAYSECS $e_epoch); do
  if [ $(date +"%m" -d "@$etime") -ne "$g_month" ]; then
    break;
  fi  
  date +"%Y-%m-%d" -d "@$etime"
done
```

Comment: Although this script doesn't work 100% right, but I get your idea: 1. use date to calculate start time and end time.
2. use seq to generate all dates. I can get this work already, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The script below work out from @perreal, I leave it here because:

1. It shows the power of GNU date.
2. It makes @perreal 's idea more clear and more universal.

Thank you, perreal!
Here it is

```
dd="2012-12-27"  # test date
DAYSECS=86400    # seconds in a day

echo "expand by week:"
s_epoch=$(date +%s -d "$dd -$(($(date +%u -d $dd) - 1)) day")                  # start date of the week
e_epoch=$(date +%s -d "1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 +${s_epoch} seconds +6 days")   # end date of the week
for etime in $(seq $s_epoch $DAYSECS $e_epoch); do
  date +"%Y-%m-%d" -d "@$etime";
done

echo "expand by month:"
s_epoch=$(date +%s -d "$dd -$(($(date +%d -d $dd) - 1)) day")                           # start date of the month
e_epoch=$(date +%s -d "1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 +${s_epoch} seconds +1 month -1 day")  # end date of the month
for etime in $(seq $s_epoch $DAYSECS $e_epoch); do
  date +"%Y-%m-%d" -d "@$etime";
done
```